# What is God's name?

Tags: terminology, names-of-god

Is it Yahweh or is it Elohim? Do those words mean the same? I heard both these words being used in the comment section to the song what if God was one of us. One line in the song goes, If God had a name would you call him to his face?

Comment: God has many names besides Yahweh and Elohim. This question is too broad.

Comment: The Son of God, once manifested in humanity called God 'Father'. And he taught his disciples to pray saying 'Our Father ...'.

Comment: @Kris it is opinion based on virtue of the section that says “If God had a name, what would you call him to his face?”

Comment: The actual difficulty is between Jehovah or Yahweh.  These are pronunciation of the Name.  Elohim is a title.  As in Jehovah Elohim, Jehovah Nissi, Jehovah Jireh, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yahweh](https://www.desiringgod.org/articles/10-things-yahweh-means): I AM. This name is generally considered to be the sacred Hebrew name of God and not meant to be spoken (according to the dictionary definition).

[Elohim](https://www.gotquestions.org/meaning-of-Elohim.html): This is generally understood to mean "The living God".

What we address God as is up to the speaker. It would probably be wise to address him with reverence and honor. Calling him "Abba" (father) would be appropriate, calling him "Lord", calling him "God", it's really just up to the person and their culture.